# Error ionic build ios?

Tags: ionic, cordova

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente error en ionic version 1? Al compilar con `ionic build ios` me lanza el siguiente error:

> CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/saltala.app saltala/Images.xcassets
>       cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/build/saltala.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/saltala.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/build/saltala.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/saltala.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.ionicframework.saltala907366.sticker-pack. --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --platform iphonesimulator --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/build/emulator/saltala.app /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/saltala/Images.xcassets
>
> /* com.apple.actool.errors */
>
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/saltala/Images.xcassets: error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching app icon set named  "AppIcon".
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/saltala/Images.xcassets: error: None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named  "LaunchImage".
>   /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/build/saltala.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/saltala.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>       CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/saltala.app saltala/Images.xcassets
>   (1 failure)
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,saltala.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,saltala,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/saltala/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Antes me funcionaba bien, ahora no sé qué pudo haber pasado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estos errores comúnmente se dan por permisos o errores en la estructura de la plataforma y se pueden solucionar de varias formas:

1. Prueba removiendo la plataforma, añadiendola de nuevo y compilando

   > ionic platform remove ios
   >   ionic platform add ios
   >   ionic build ios
2. Puedes probar también cambiando los permisos en las carpetas usadas para compilar el proyecto:

   > sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
   >   sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config